# I need to use locks but dont know how in a networking problem

Tags: networking, server, graphics, thread-sleep, qt-signals

this is put in a for in my server.py archive of networking. The messages are sent to my archive named Client.py , the messages are getting to Client.py, but the signals are not showed well.
down here i leave my code for server.py and after the code in Client.py

```
server.py:

self.mensaje( f'turno de {self.turno_actual}')
self.mensaje(f'turno anterior : {self.turno_anterior}')
self.mensaje(f'turno numero {self.numero_turno}')

Client.py:

mensaje = self.recibir_mensaje()

if 'turno anterior :' in mensaje:
                    print(mensaje[-2:], self.num_jugador
                    self.senal_turno_anterior.emit(int(mensaje[-2:]))
            

elif 'turno de' in mensaje:
                    self.senal_actualizar_jugador.emit(str(mensaje[-1]))
                    
                        

elif 'turno numero' in mensaje:
                    self.senal_num_turno.emit(int(turno))
```

I tried putting time.sleep(1) so the graphics had time to process the information sent, but it didn't help. I'm expecting for the signals to be sent when their functions called.